# In a sink drain stopper lift - Is there a more robust way of connecting the lift rod to the lift strap besides the tightening nut?

Tags: sink, fastener

I have a standard lift rod and lift rod strap conected by a tightening nut.  The issue is that no matter how tight I make the nut, since the lift rod strap wire is a bit thinner than the holes in the lift rod strap, there is some play in the alignment and the tightening screw can slip/push past the thin wire and lose the tension, falling apart.

Is there a more robust way of connecting the lift rod to the strap that doesn't rely on the precise alignment of the tightening screw to land dead center on the lift rod?  Perhaps some sort of cable stopper or other way to add some sort of other clamp to that connection?

[image]

Comment: Have you used a wrench on the thumbscrew? I always find that hand tightening is insufficient.

Comment: I can tighten it - it just slips off the center of rod since there is play in the hole between the lift rod and strap and the

Comment: Sorry, didn't fully grasp the issue. I'd either buy new parts or tap the strap for a bigger thumbscrew.